# addEventListener doesnt fire on click in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have the below code and the "alert" doesn't happen on click on the said element.
But addEventListener seems to be supported by the IE I use (version 10) as I checked with another simple program and it worked fine.

```
var iframe1 = document.getElementsByName('frStatus')[0];
var innerDoc = (iframe1.contentDocument) ? iframe1.contentDocument : iframe1.contentWindow.document;
innerDoc.getElementById('slow_jquery').innerHTML = slowjquerycount;
innerDoc.getElementById('slow_jquery').style.color="red";
console.log("doc"+document.getElementById("slow_jquery"));
innerDoc.getElementById('slow_jquery').addEventListener("click", function(){
       alert("event listener");
});
```

The corresponding html is

```
<span id="slow_jquery" style="cursor:pointer;color:green;">0</span>
```

When the above code is executed & the element is clicked, no error is thrown, no warning on console, and the alert message is not shown. Is there anything wrong with the code ? Any help is going to be of much use.

Thanks in advance.

Note:
 - Already tried using z-index to ensure the element is not hidden behind another.
 - Code works fine in Chrome.
 - Ensured that IE-10 supports addEventListener.

Comment: Your understanding of events is broken. Have you tried to click on the button before posting the question?

Comment: Why wouldnt I ? I did

Comment: By "executed", I meant onclick ! I know what an event listener on "click" is intended to do

Comment: Is the iframe from another site? Or is it in the same domain?

Comment: No.. It is from the same. And the code works fine on chrome..

Comment: IE-10 as I have mentioned in the question

Comment: Are you sure that the element inside the iframe exists when the code is executed?

Comment: Yes I am sure about it.. I had the same doubt and tested by removing the element  and got "cannot attach addEventListener to null" error.

Comment: Do you have any other event attached to the same element?

Comment: That is incredibly weird. Are you sure that there isn't any transparent element over the button or over the iframe?

Comment: Yes I am absolutely sure.. I am just wondering why it works in Chrome and not in IE.. If there was another element stopping the click from hitting slow_jquery, it shudnt fire on Chrome too right! But it works der

Comment: Not exactly. It could be the result of a difference on CSS handling, since IE10 is old. And that could place something transparent above the iframe. It happened to me before.

Comment: Oh really? Do you think z-index could help there ?

Comment: Yes, it could. But can you add some html to the question? Also, before someone deletes the comments, you should make a list of things you've already checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `element.onclick=function` instead of registering `'click'` event listener.

Comment: You mean the HTML property, the object property or the old-style event?

Comment: @Anu145 you can try to add the 3rd argument with value `false` to the `addEventListener` call, by IE it is not optional

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to bind a listener to a dynamically added element. That's easy in [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). In plain JS it's a bit more difficult: you'll have to use event delegation.

Make sure the argument to querySelector is an element that exists on load, and isn't added dynamically! In this case I assume that `iframe1` is such an element.

```
document.querySelector(iframe1).addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target.id === "slow_jquery") {
    alert("event listener");
  }
});
```

Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14259372/1150683):

> CAVEATS! The example Fiddle only includes code for the
>   standards-compliant browsers (i.e., IE9+, and pretty much every
>   version of everyone else) If you need to support "old IE's"
>   attachEvent, then you'll want to also provide your own custom wrapper
>   around the proper native functions. (There are lots of good
>   discussions out there about this; I like the solution Nicholas Zakas
>   provides in his book Professional JavaScript for Web Developers.)

Comment: Tried all of these but didnt work.. element.onclick worked instead. Thanks