# Adding onclick event on dynamic checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a 'CRUD' in pure Javascript, it's almost done, the only thing that I need is preparing the inputs with the value of `<li>`, to do it, I'd like to add an `onclick` event in a checkbox that is created dynamically in the function `insert()`, but everytime I click the checkbox nothing happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        btnInsert = document.getElementById("btnInsert");
        btnEdit = document.getElementById("btnEdit");
        btnDelete = document.getElementById("btnDelete");
        vname = document.getElementById("tbName");
        ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];

        btnInsert.onclick = insert;
        btnDelete.onclick = remove;
    }

    function insert(){
        li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = vname.value;
        li.innerHTML += " <input type='checkbox' onclick='select()'          value='Select' /> Update"; 
        ul.appendChild(li);
        vname.value = "";
    }

    function select(){
        alert("Checked");
    }

    function remove(){              
        var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for(i = 0; i<lis.length; i++){
            lis[i].onclick = function(){
            this.remove();
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="tbName">Name: </label> 
<input name="tbName" id="tbName"/><br /><br />
<button id="btnInsert">Insert</button> 
<button id="btnEdit">Edit</button> 
<button id="btnDelete">Delete</button>
<br /><br />
<ul>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add event listener on elements created dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258787/add-event-listener-on-elements-created-dynamically)

Comment: In your insert function add the event listener to the `li` like this: `li.addEventListener('click', callback);' where `callback` is the function you want to bind to the event. EDIT: on second look, you are adding the input INTO a list item, in that case you just need to use " instead of  ' and it should work. Also i think your script has an extra } at the end?

Comment: 1) `addEventListener` is probably what you want. 2) Try to avoid having lots of global variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the name `select` is causing conflict since I could get your code working with the following changes:

*HTML*

```
li.innerHTML += " <input type='checkbox' onclick='sel()' value='Select' />Update";
```

*Javascript*

```
function sel(){
    alert("Checked");
}
```

Further tests show that if we log the contents of the function with:

```
li.innerHTML += " <input type='checkbox' onclick='console.log(select.toString)' value='Select' />Update";
```

the console shows the following

```
function select() { [native code] }
```

So my guess is that `select` is the name of a function already defined by the browser, hence why you can't use it as a name for your functions.

**In short**, your code triggers another `select` function, not the one you defined in your source code.

Answer (score 1):

The OP doesn't want it to fire on the `LI`, he wants it to fire on the `checkbox`!

Give your dynamic checkbox an ID value like `chkBox1`.
Now after you have appended it to the document, you can call it with:

```
var thechkBox=document.getElementById("chkBox1");
```

Now you can hit `thechkBox` with:

```
thechkBox.addEventListener("click", itfired); //itfired is the script that captures the click event.
```

That is one of many Events you would then have access to (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp)!

If you needed the dynamic checkbox to perform a function "on"click!