# Javascript - add event listener to elements added with insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: javascript

I am creating elements in a for loop and would like to add event listener to all of them, but not sure how to do that?

```
for (let i = numberOfPages; i >  0; i--){
    var link = navLinksTemplate({ pageNumber: i });
    previous.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', link);
  }
```

I need to do it with vanilla js.

Comment: What about giving them a specific class and have the event listener on that class with the `querySelector` ([*see this*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258787/add-event-listener-on-elements-created-dynamically)).

Comment: Scroll down to the 5th answer in the linked question to see how to do it without jQuery.

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery, I need to do it with vanilla javascript