# Trouble with to-do list close button

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have some code that seems to be working, but in a rather odd fashion. When I first refresh the page I have the close button that seems to work fine, but when I make a new to-do list item the close button seems to cease working and I can't pinpoint why.

```js
let addItem = document.getElementById("submitButton");
let userInput = document.getElementById("toDoInput");
let output = document.getElementById("output");
let toDoItem = document.querySelector(".toDoItem");
let close = document.querySelector(".close");
let toDo = document.querySelector(".todo");

/*User clicked the addItem Button
If there is any text inside the text field then add that text to the todo list */
addItem.addEventListener("click", addToDo);
function addToDo(){
  var html = `
  <ul class="todo">
      <li class="toDoItem">
        <p>${userInput.value}</p>
        <div class="close">X</div>
      </li>
  </ul>
  `;
output.innerHTML += html;
// Resetting input to blank once a submit button has been added.
userInput.value = '';
}


// Figure out how to make closing functionality simple this implementation
// isn't working
close.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  console.log("clicked");
  let x = e.target.parentElement;
  x.style.display = "none";
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<header>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Item Here..." id="toDoInput">
    <button id="submitButton">+</button>
</header>

<section id="output">
    <ul class="todo">
        <li class="toDoItem">
          <p>Clean Room!</p>
          <div class="close">X</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
<script src="todo.js"></script>
```

I'm also not sure if I'm using best practice as I'm new to web development, so any tips would be thoroughly appreciated as well!

Comment: You're building the `.close` elements dynamically, so you need to make use of `event delegation`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a live event handler on your close button(s). [This example](https://plainjs.com/javascript/events/live-binding-event-handlers-14/) should help. To offer something more, it's easier and more straight forward to use jQuery for it if you can and don't mind using a JS library.

jQuery example:

```
$(document).on("click", ".close", function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

No need to prevent default behavior since it's a div.

Comment: This answer is in JQuery so remember to place it OUTSIDE `document.ready`

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that when you re-render the content of the "output" section you lose the event listener bound to the original ".close" element. A few options to work around the issue, have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258787/add-event-listener-on-elements-created-dynamically) for some examples.

Comment: Exactly, it cannot listen to what wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

You got pretty close man, and you definitely do not need jQuery.
As you can see below, you don't need to push the `<ul>` dynamically. It will never change!

```
<header>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Item Here..." id="toDoInput">
    <button id="submitButton">+</button>

</header>

<section id="output">
    <ul class="todo">
    </ul>
</section>
```

And here is your refactored javascript:

```
let addItem = document.getElementById("submitButton");
let userInput = document.getElementById("toDoInput");
let output = document.getElementById("output");
let toDoItem = document.querySelector(".toDoItem");
let toDo = document.querySelector(".todo");

/*User clicked the addItem Button
If there is any text inside the text field then add that text to the todo 
list */
addItem.addEventListener("click", addToDo);

function addToDo(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var html = `<li class="toDoItem">
                <p>${userInput.value} </p> <p class="close" 
                onclick="removeChildElement(this);">X</p>
                </li>`;
   output.innerHTML += html;
   let close = document.querySelector(".close")
    // Resetting input to blank once a submit button has been added.
    userInput.value = '';
}


// Figure out how to make closing functionality simple this implementation
// isn't working
function removeChildElement(e) {
    let x = e.parentElement;
    let xParent = x.parentElement;
    xParent.removeChild(x);
    console.log(xParent);
}
```

As you can see i made a few changes. Most importantly your close button issue. The function gets the parent on its parent ( ^ 2 ) and then removes its child. Which would be your `<li>` element!

Enjoy the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fjbyy6uw/35/

Answer (score 0):

Use [Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm). Details are commented in Demo. Added a `<form>` so [HTMLFormControlsCollection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) can be used, it's simpler, less writing, and I'm lazy.

```js
/* All form controls are referenced by HTMLFormControlsCollection */
var form = document.forms.toDo;
var td = form.elements;
var add = td.add;
var inp = td.input;
var out = td.output;
var toDo = document.querySelector('.toDo');

add.addEventListener("click", addToDo);

/* Limited the dynamically created node to `<li>`. It doesn't make sense to
|| have several `<ul>` having only one `<li>` each.
*/
function addToDo() {
  var html = `
       <li class="item">
        <span>${inp.value}</span>
        <b class="close">X</b>
      </li>
  `;
  toDo.innerHTML += html;

}
/* Event Delegation is a way of leveraging event bubbling so
|| that a single ancestor node can be registered to listen for
|| an event (e.currentTarget) and by means event propagation
|| (bubbling) can locate the event origin (node clicked/e.target).
|| In this demo e.currentTarget is output#output and e.target are
|| any b.close. This was possibble by using e.target in conditions
*/
/* removeChild() is used because display:none is not entirely 
|| gone. The markup remains just not in the DOM, so it may not
|| look like it's there, under certain conditions a node could be
|| considered present.
*/
out.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    if (e.target.className === "close") {
      let x = e.target.parentElement
      x.parentElement.removeChild(x);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 250px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item span,
.item b {
  display: table-cell;
}

.item b {
  cursor: pointer
}

input,
output,
button {
  font: inherit
}
```

```html
<form id='toDo'>
  <header>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Item Here..." id="input">
    <button id="add" type='button'>+</button>
  </header>

  <output id="output">
    <ul class="toDo">
        <li class="item">
          <span>Clean Room!</span>
          <b class="close">X</b>
        </li>
    </ul>
</output>

</form>
```