# How to get value from input that added dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I'm new in js .I'm dynamically adding new inputs and I want to get value from that input. How to add event listener for it?

```
  addNewInput(i) {
    const input = document.getElementsByClassName("scenario-inputs")
    let newInput = document.createElement("input")
    newInput.className = "dynamicInput"
    input[i].appendChild(newInput)
  }
```

Comment: If you instead had a array of inputs that you push new input identifiers to and created components using something like map() you could much more easily keep track of each component as well as avoiding manual DOM manipulation. Manually adding elements is completely underutilizing React and components.

Comment: addEventListener

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add event listener on elements created dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258787/add-event-listener-on-elements-created-dynamically)

Comment: If you are adding the new inputs you can just add onChange hooks to it. But if they are being added by some third party library you will need to recur to some sort of refs

Answer (score 1):

You sort of answered your own question, every time you add your new input you just need to [add a new event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for it.

```
addNewInput(i) {
  const input = document.getElementsByClassName("scenario-inputs")
  let newInput = document.createElement("input")
  newInput.className = "dynamicInput"
  input[i].appendChild(newInput)
  newInput.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
      // do something ...
  }
}
```

Comment: on "change" it doesn't work. It works on 'keydown'. What can be the porblem?

Comment: Ah the change event "is not necessarily fired for each alteration to an element's value.", according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change. So you can use 'keydown', or 'input' event handlers instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `react` then that's a bad way to add elements dynamically. 
You can maintain an array which holds the information of each of the input elements and on `addNewInput`, just push a new entry to the array and react will render it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
addNewInput(i) {
  const input = document.getElementsByClassName("scenario-inputs")
  let newInput = document.createElement("input")
  newInput.className = "dynamicInput"
  input[i].appendChild(newInput)
  newInput.onchange = function () {to be implemented.}
}
```

It is enough to bind a listener. Whenever a change occurs in the input, your function is going to be invoked so that you can read the input's value.