# How to remove $(document).on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code to add event

```
   $(document).on({
      click: function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#form_name').removeClass('hide');
        $('#form_template_name')
          .attr('placeholder', $(this).text())
          .focus();
      }         
    }, '.form-template-name');
```

For some conditions i dont want this event to trigger. So what I tried is

```
$('.form-template-name').off();
$('.form-template-name').unbind();
```

But nothing seems to work. Did I miss anything ?

Comment: You need to know that `$(document).on` binds to the `document`, not the target selector element, it applies the selector *when the event occurs*. You need to remove it from the same level it is attached to.

Comment: I couldn't find any ways to remove from same level.

Comment: Arun P Johny's answer appears to work (removes any clicked element, then removes the handler on the button press), but perhaps we misunderstand your question. **Please explain the desired behaviour.**

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie It was my mistake. Indeed Arun P Johny's answer works

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to pass the event to unbind to .off(), also see the use of namepsaced event names

```
$(document).on({
    'click.myevent': function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#form_name').removeClass('hide');
        $('#form_template_name')
            .attr('placeholder', $(this).text())
            .focus();
    }
}, '.form-template-name');
```

and

```
$(document).off('click.myevent', '.form-template-name');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/H3yRa/)

Comment: Clicking on the button should not trigger the event handler, but then clicking elsewhere *should*, but you've removed it entirely.

Comment: @Quentin I didn't understand what you want to say, what the solution for the OP
?

Comment: @shiva can you update the fiddle to explain your problem

Comment: @C-link what Quentin says is it might be related to ignoring certain elements from causing the handler to trigger

Comment: @ArunPJohny My mistake. Works like a charm. And can you please explain diffrence btween `click` and `click.myevent` no proper results in google.

Comment: @shiva it is called [namespaced event names](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names)...  it is used because if you just use `click` as the event name and there is another click handler added to the target element by some other code then when you use `.off()` it will remove all other handlers too instead of just the handler we are looking for... if you use namespaces you can escape from that

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
$(document).off('click', '.form-template-name');
```

Answer (score 1):

An event handler is bound to an element. You can unbind an event handler from the element it is attached to, but you can't unbind it from a descendant element since that isn't where it is listening.

You can either:

1. Examine [the `target` property](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) of the event object (the first argument to your event handler function) to see what element was clicked on and then `return` before doing anything.
2. Bind a new event handler to the elements you want stop the event from triggering from and [prevent the event from continuing up the DOM](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
var clickEvent = function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#form_name').removeClass('hide');
    $('#form_template_name')
      .attr('placeholder', $(this).text())
      .focus();
};

$(document).on({
   click: clickEvent         
}, '.form-template-name');
```

And unbind it with:

```
$(document).unbind('click', clickEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your click handler to:

```
$(document).on({
    'click.myevent': function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#form_name').removeClass('hide');
        $('#form_template_name')
            .attr('placeholder', $(this).text())
            .focus();
    }
}, '.form-template-name');
```

then you can use **[.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)**, with name spaced **[event names](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names)**:

```
$(document).off('click.myevent', '.form-template-name');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('.form-template-name').unbind("click"", event);
```

and define the click event as:

```
var event = function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#form_name').removeClass('hide');
    $('#form_template_name')
      .attr('placeholder', $(this).text())
      .focus();
};
```

Then use it as you did before.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try using the **event.preventDefault()** functionality. It is described in more detail here: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/