# Jquery disable previous function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).on('touchstart click', function (){
        $('#box').hide();
});

if(isset($_GET['s'])){include(//another page);}
```

another page will disable document click `$('#box').hide();`

I have a page, if get variable isset, It will include another page.

However I need to disable a document click hide div function

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, this might work:

```
myvar = 0;

$(document).on('touchstart click', function (){
        if(myvar==0){
            $('#box').hide();
        }
});

if(isset($_GET['s'])){
    include(//another page);
    myvar = 1;
}
```

Comment: possible not touch previous code and disable from another page?

Comment: Im not sure this is totally relevant, but take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400907/how-to-remove-document-on-click-event