# .on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd') only fires once

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, razor

I have an animation and after the animation is complete I use a partial view to update the data.
`.on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd')` only seems to be firing the first time. Any idea why this is happening, it's like the JQuery isn't recognizing the `$('#marqueeTop span')`.Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m95pzsau/4/) of what I would like it to do.

**Partial**

```
<div id="marqueeTop">
    <span class="moveTop">
        @foreach(var item in Model){
            <label>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.GroupName)
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Sales ).....
            </label>   
        }
    </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#marqueeTop {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#marqueeTop span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    text-indent: 0;
    font-family:wallStreetFont;
}
.moveTop{
    animation: marqueeTop 5s linear infinite;
    animation-iteration-count:1;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
 $('#marqueeTop span').on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function () {
    $.get('/Home/GetBookingsTicker', function (response) {
        $('#marqueeTop').replaceWith(response);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attaching an `eventListener` on `#marqueeTop span` and within this listener you remove (replace) `#marqueeTop`. (`$('#marqueeTop').replaceWith(response);`)

Since you remove `#marqueeTop` you also remove your own `eventListener` (on the `<span>`).
Here is another question as reference: [If a DOM Element is removed, are its listeners also removed from memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528049/if-a-dom-element-is-removed-are-its-listeners-also-removed-from-memory)

You can use a delegated event handler with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on
>   the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that
>   match the selector.

```
$('body').on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', '#marqueeTop span', function () {
    $.get('/Home/GetBookingsTicker', function (response) {
        $('#marqueeTop').replaceWith(response);
    });
});
```

Like this you can remove and add the `#marqueeTop` and still have a eventListener on this element.

**Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m95pzsau/5/**