# Removing event listeners for removed nodes

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I am adding event listeners to nodes at runtime based on mutations by a `MutationObserver` such as click drag etc...,now when the child node that i added the event listeners to gets removed from the node i am observing am i supposed to remove the event listeners i added to it or do the listeners removed when a node gets removed from the dom?

Comment: I hope   [This will help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528049/if-a-dom-element-is-removed-are-its-listeners-also-removed-from-memory)

Comment: @NagarajS thanks a lot thats all i wanted to know