# Why is this img.onload handler ever called?

Tags: javascript, dom, garbage-collection, message-queue

Looking to understand memory leaks in Javascript at the circular reference of DOM and JS objects thought that the following `isOnloadCalled()` would **not** yield "yes", but it does. why?

```
function isOnloadCalled() {
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function () {
        console.log("yes");
    };

    img.src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAxJREFUCNdj+P//PwAF/gL+3MxZ5wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
}

isOnloadCalled();
// yields: "yes"
```

For my confusion is related to the idea that the DOM object `img` was created within the function scope of `isOnloadCalled()` and via closure is also within its `img.onload` handler. I would expect that the `img` gets garbage collected as soon as becomes unreachable and hence its `onload` handler was never triggered. 
Since the a test in Chrome and Firefox showed that the result is an unexpected "yes", and the object was not garbage collected I seek in this question an answer detailling why the DOM.object's handler was calledd when indeed the DOM already lost all its reachable references and should have been garbage collected, even more so as it was never attached to the documents DOM tree.

Since before any event handler can be envoked there is the Javascript "Run-to-completion" paradigm and hence amble time for the browser to check `img` is not referenced anymore and can be deleted, by this making a call to the onload handler obsolete.

The only explenation I have kind of come up with, and which may serve as part of an answer would be that with the `isOnloadCalled()` last line being `img.src = "[url]"` the still existing `img` is "kept reachable" via its reference by the events that reference it from within the javascript message queue. But I am unsure if this is the right explanation.

Comment: I think your last sentence is the right answer, `img.src = "[url]" `here you use `img` and assigned to its property `src` a value, so the browser will wait until the new image url is loaded, at the same time, you added a listener to its loaded event >> fire

Comment: This question could be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528049/if-a-dom-element-is-removed-are-its-listeners-also-removed-from-memory

Comment: @MuhammadAref That means that the `roots` for mark and sweep garbage collection are the global object (e.g `window`), the document's DOM tree and **in addition** also Javascript Message Queue then? In retrospective that would make really much sense. Even though I first incorrectly thought it would simply skip Message Queue messages that relates to obsoleted objects. (i.e. not invoke a onload to an else unreferenced img). The bright sight then is that in this way onload is assured to run at least once upon src is called, no matter what else happens (function scope exits)

Comment: @Reda the question you refer to is really shadding some light on the question I raised too. thank you.