# Can someone clarify when I need to worry about using scope.$on("destroy")

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, memory-leaks

I've read many many articles on the topic of when to use scope.$on("$destroy") but I haven't been able to identify when to apply it in practice. I'm not looking for a "In this case you would..." answer" I'm looking for a clarification to know myself when (to/to not) worry about applying it.

here's a couple of the articles I've read.
[Angular Documentation for scope](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)
[Always trigger the destroy event before removing dom elements](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2706-always-trigger-the-destroy-event-before-removing-elements-in-angularjs-directives.htm)
[If a dom element is removed are it's listeners removed as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528049/if-a-dom-element-is-removed-are-its-listeners-also-removed-from-memory)
[How the destroy event affects the scope tree](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2883-how-the-destroy-event-affects-the-scope-tree-in-angularjs.htm)

given a very simple directive that doesn't even have it's own scope. This directive scrolls an item into the screen and keeps it there.

```
angular.module("scrollIf").directive("scrollIf", ["$window", "$timeout",
    function ($window, $timeout) {
        "use strict";
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                var css = attrs.scrollIf;
                var scrollElement = $window.document.getElementsByClassName(css)[0];

                var handler = element.on("click", function (event) {

                    scope.$parent.$digest(); //update everything first
                    $timeout(function () {

                        var elementViewPortTop = element[0].getBoundingClientRect().top + (element[0].getBoundingClientRect().height / 2);
                        var scrollPosition = scrollElement.scrollTop + (elementViewPortTop - event.clientY);

                        scrollElement.scrollTop = scrollPosition;
                    }, 1);

                });

            }
        };
    }]);
```

given this example, do I need to worry about $destroy?  I am attaching a handler directly to the dom, not to scope. so when the parent gets destroyed is this example leaving detached objects in memory that don't have references?

Also, why is `$scope.$on("click")` different than `element.on("click")`? If I use the `controllerAs` syntax and bind to controller. I don't inject the `$scope` service into my directive. In that case is `$scope.$on` the same as link's `scope.$on`?

Comment: That's the question that helped muddy my understanding. It's not clear if the some of the code snippets in the answer are the example of the problem, or the example of the fix.

Comment: As I can see, all the snippets in the answer are examples of 'good' code. Your question is pretty much mixed up, the second part (*Also, ...*) doesn't make much sense and isn't related to the first part at all. Your particular example is relatively safe, it is unlikely that `scope` will be destroyed before `element`, the POI is `scrollElement` - if it will be removed before `element` for some reason, it will leak.

Comment: Yes, I did tack on the second part. But, I think we can close this as a duplicate and I'll ask the answerer of the other question if he can confirm the examples are as you believe the 'good' versions. He also did answer the final paragraph of my question. Even if it isn't related.