# Do I need to removeEventListener on pause and addEventListener on play?

Tags: aframe

I looked at the post [When do I need to call removeEventListener in my components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801404/when-do-i-need-to-call-removeeventlistener-in-my-components/40872971) but it did not address my question.

I've heard that its best practice to `removeEventListener` on pause and `addEventListener` on play in order to maintain consistent (to other components) `click` functionality while using the A-Frame inspector. Thus your code would look like this:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('my-component', {
  init: function() {
    this.doSomething = function() {
      console.log("I'm doing it")
    }
  },
  play: function() {
    this.el.addEventListener('click', this.doSomething)
  },
  pause: function() {
    this.el.removeEventListener('click', this.doSomething)
  }
})
```

It seems to me that if the A-Frame inspector needs this to be done to work properly, then it should handle this for me instead of making me do it for every event listener I add. Is there any merit to this claim?

Other than the A-Frame Inspector aspect, could there be a situation where code running in an event handler while the scene is partially initialized or partially destroyed could cause hard to diagnose bugs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important pieces are:

1. That the event listeners get cleaned up after the entity is removed or detached from the scene. When entities get removed, not only is the `.remove` handler called, but so is the `.pause` handler.
2. Yes, so the event listeners don't run when the Inspector is open. This might not be as important within the context of an application, but useful to implement if you are sharing a generalized component where people might use the Inspector to poke around.

In any case, if you're going to add event listeners, you might as well use `.play` and `.pause`. It doesn't hurt and make sure things run cleanly in every case.