# Garbage collection / removal of XHR Event listeners like load, progress

Tags: javascript, events, xmlhttprequest, addeventlistener

When I create an browser XMLHttpRequest and create event listeners like load, readystatechange, progress will they get destroyed when the XHR request completes (error/success) OR do I have to manually destroy them?

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: Might not need an example. I am requesting the lifecycle of events if we need to manually remove them. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: also relevant http://stackoverflow.com/a/12528067/4769440

Answer (score 0):

Event emitters and listeners get collected like all other objects, so the xhr listeners will get collected when the "parent" xhr instance will be.

Comment: Ok does that mean that if - 1) I create a new XMLHttpRequest, 2) make a request, 3) create eventlisteners for all request events then >> when the XMLHttpRequest finishes with a loadend all the request events are garbage collected automatically?