# X-editable does not work after insertion

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

jQuery library: https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/index.html

After inserting the HTML code into the block:

```
$.get(url, ->
    return
).done((data)->
    document.getElementById('js-block').innerHTML = data['result']
    return
)
```

X-editable stops working.

The JS code above updates the contents of the div block.

After loading the page, clicking on the link opens the field. And the information was successfully updated.

But as soon as the contents of the block were updated with JS's help, the X-editable library stopped working (not initialized - apparently).

I found nothing in the documentation. The `.enable()` call did not help. The library developer says to go to stackoverflow.

Comment: My guess, any handler attached to any parts of the dom elements replaced is gone. They need to be rebound. Unless you have a deferred binding on a higher parent. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528049/if-a-dom-element-is-removed-are-its-listeners-also-removed-from-memory

Comment: @Fran I do not understand how this can help me. I just need to somehow enable X-editable after inserting HTML code into the page.

Comment: @Fran This does not help me.

Comment: Hence I only left a comment and not an answer! I mentioned a link based on a guess what I thought might be helpful, if it it wasn't and I didn't understand the issue, ignore the comment :)