# Javascript : when DOM removed, then its event listeners are also removed?

Tags: javascript, dom, listeners

I cannot find clear answer about my question.

I've removed DOM element which had event listener.

Surely, DOM element have been removed, but I cannot know its listeners also removed.

Comment: yes they are: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528049/if-a-dom-element-is-removed-are-its-listeners-also-removed-from-memory

Comment: Is it okay to understand "event listeners are belonging to DOM"?

Comment: well if there are no more references to that element, then when the garbage collector removes the DOM element, it will remove the events associated with that element. The DOM element belongs to the DOM and the associated event "belongs" to that element, but dont overthink it

Comment: Thanks, I got it. :)

Comment: If the event listeners weren't removed, what would they listen for?