# Reduce Javascript memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory, memory-leaks, datatables

I have been trying to reduce javascript memory used by our web application ([single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) without MVC framework with jQuery & Bootstrap and a lot of Plugins ). And remove memory leaks we have. In our web application, there is a dashboard filled with Highcharts. It can be of any number can be 0 or can be 50 on the basis of user's choice. There are plenty of pages with Datatables, there are a lot of forms to create update data through the app.

Now I have been called to reduce memory usage. I have reduced memory leaks using google chrome developer tools by using "Heap Shot Profiling" in memory tab. As on refresh of charts I was adding a new chart and not deleting old chart. So after removing old chart which is replaced made a good impact. Still, we want to dig dipper and see what else we can improve.

Right now I am seeing the same thing with our DataTables we are adding new Datatables whenever you go to a new page. After checking I found out that we are not destroying them after, destroying them do not make that impact what, we had with Highcharts.

Here we call a jQuery ajax call to change the content of the page. We use ".html( newContent )" to change text in our main container as well as with every HTML element in which we want to change content as per [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12528067/2542806) it says it should remove all the event listeners and references to those elements should be removed but still data tables are present in memory. And maybe many other things.

Furthermore, I tried removing BODY tag and checking memory screenshots. The size of the screenshot remains same. It shows a lot of elements have been de-attached. But its impact on Javascript Memory usage and Javascript memory allocation is near to 0.

Am I on the right path to reduce Memory leaks. Or there is nothing I can do now more?

There are few screenshots.

These all screenshots are after removing the all the children of the body tag. Like if we remove all of the elements it should have low javascript memory usage but here I see change near to 0.

Here you can see we are still using 50MB in javascript Memory. 
[image]

We are still having Datatables in our memory.
[image]

There is an increase in the snapshot and also increase in memory allocation. Yes, there are decreases in memory allocation at down where it shows unattached elements but it is nominal. 
[image]

What should be the interpretation of all these data?

I have read a lot of StackOverflow questions regarding this and blogs for memory leaks. But nothing is making a big impact?

Comment: Have you tried calling [`destroy()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()) on the DataTables before removing them?

Comment: Yes. I tried calling destroy() on DataTables it become _Api but it did not have an impact on memory allocation. But yeah I am definitely going to destroy data tables in next page load everytime.