# is removeEventListener necessary if external references to target are removed?

Tags: javascript

If I listen for events on `obj` like this:

```
obj.addEventListener("click", listener)
```

Assuming that `obj` is only referenced from another object (`obj2.obj = obj`), if at some point of the execution of the program, this reference is removed (`obj2.obj = null`), will `obj` get garbage collected or do I need to call `obj.removeEventListener("click", listener)` first? I don't have a deep understanding of the GC in JS VMs, so I'm not sure if there's some circular dependency introduced by the listener that might keep `obj` alive forever. Does it depend on additional properties of `obj` or `listener` actually is? I know it can get especially complicated with things like `listener.bind(this)`, or even worse `listener.bind(obj)`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a DOM Element is removed, are its listeners also removed from memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528049/if-a-dom-element-is-removed-are-its-listeners-also-removed-from-memory)