# How to remove event listener from a Backdrop which is being dismounted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, react-hooks, removeeventlistener

I have a `Backdrop_DIV` which is rendered based on a `open` for a Dropdown component.

```
{open &&
  <LS.Backdrop_DIV
    onClick={handleBackdropClick}
    ref={backdrop_ref}
  >
    Backdrop
  </LS.Backdrop_DIV>
}
```

I want the `Backdrop_DIV` to go away if the user scrolls (`touchmove`).

**Obs:** This is a mobile view.

```
const handleTouchMove = useCallback(()=>{
    setOpen(false);
  },[]);
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
      // ATTACHING THE EVENT LISTENR
      backdrop_ref.current.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove );
    }

    // ATTEMPT TO REMOVE THE EVENT LISTENER
    return () => 
      backdrop_ref.current.removeEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove);

},[open,handleScroll]);
```

It works, but if fails when I'm trying to clear the event listener in the return of my `useEffect`. Is there a way to do this?

**Error:**

> react-dom.development.js:20313 Uncaught TypeError: **Cannot read property 'removeEventListener' of null**

This error is pretty obvious, because the `Backdrop_DIV` is no longer mounted when it runs.

**QUESTION**

Do I need to bother removing the event listener in this case? What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried to use `componentWillUnmount`?

Comment: @mindmaster I'm using React Hooks and functional components only. There's no `componentWillUnmount` available. Thanks!

Comment: is open no longer true when you attempt to remove the event listener? If it isn't then it looks like LS.Backgrop_div is no longer being displayed, this is perhaps why backdrop.current is no longer defined. If the DOM element no longer exists, should you also remove the event listener, I am not sure, perhaps this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528049/if-a-dom-element-is-removed-are-its-listeners-also-removed-from-memory

Comment: np @cbdev420 :) should I post the above as an answer to your question or do you need further help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From question recommended by Carlene in the comments, I would say that it's not necessary to remove the event listener, since it will be handled by the garbage Collector, although some older browser might leak memory in this situation.

[If a DOM Element is removed, are its listeners also removed from memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528049/if-a-dom-element-is-removed-are-its-listeners-also-removed-from-memory)

But also, I found a way to remove the listener before dismounting the `Backdrop_DIV` and it works:

- I added a `lastOpenState_ref` `useRef()` keep track of the previous render `open` state so I can detect the render that will dismount the `Backdrop_DIV` (`open === false`) and I remove the listener during that render.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback} from 'react';

function MyComponent() {

  const [open,setOpen] = useState(false);
  const backdrop_ref = useRef(null);
  const lastOpenState_ref = useRef(false);

  const handleBackdropTouchMove = useCallback(() => {
    setOpen(false);
  },[]);

  // BLOCK TO REMOVE EVENT LISTENER FROM backdrop_ref
  // SINCE IT'S IMPOSSIBLE TO REMOVE FROM THE useEffect RETURN
  // BECAUSE THE backdrop_ref IS NULL WHEN IT RUNS

  if (lastOpenState_ref.current === true && open === false) {
    backdrop_ref.current.removeEventListener('touchmove', handleBackdropTouchMove);
  }
  lastOpenState_ref.current = open;

  // EFFECT TO ATTACH 'touchmove' EVENT LISTENER ON 'backdrop_ref.current'

  useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
      backdrop_ref.current.addEventListener('touchmove', handleBackdropTouchMove);
    }
  },[open,handleBackdropTouchMove]);

  // RETURN STATEMENT

  return(
    <LS.Container_DIV>
      {open &&
        <LS.Backdrop_DIV
          onClick={handleBackdropClick}
          ref={backdrop_ref}
        >
        </LS.Backdrop_DIV>
      }
      <SomeOtherStuff/>
    </LS.Container_DIV>
  );
}
```