# will removing an HTML element going to cause his and his childrens EventListeners to get deleted?

Tags: javascript, html

lets say i have got this simple `html` code

```
<div id="0">
   <div id="0:0">
      <div id="0:0:0"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="0:1"></div>
</div>
```

now lets add some `javascript`

```
let div_ids=["0","0:0","0:0:0","0:1"];
for(let i=0;i<div_ids.length;i++){
   document.getElementById(div_ids[i]).addEventListener("click",()=>{console.log("hi");});
}
```

now we have an `EventListener` for every div
now lets execute this `javascript` code

```
document.querySelector("body").removeChild(document.getElementById("0"));
```

**my question** : will removing `div#0` delete his and his children's `EventListener`s ?

Comment: It's funny how some languages have genders for everything, but yes normally the event listeners are removed with the element (with some caveats). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528049/if-a-dom-element-is-removed-are-its-listeners-also-removed-from-memory

Comment: Technically it will not be removed, https://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/3rnauod8/

Comment: @huanfeng this fiddle only demonstrates that the setInterval callback keeps firing, it does say anything about the DOM element and its event handler.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for the comments, then i think the answer is already explained well in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528049/if-a-dom-element-is-removed-are-its-listeners-also-removed-from-memory

Comment: Sure it is. I didn't dispute that, but your claim of the inverse of what is said there.