# is the jquery event handler getting removed when removing the dom element by js

Tags: javascript, jquery

if we register an event handler like this:

`$(div1).on('event', handler ...`

and after `div1` gets removed (not by jQuery), but using plain js,

does the handler stay orphaned in memory ?

Comment: As long as the removed element is not garbage collected from the memory, the event listener stays. If the handler function itself is declared or stored in a variable, it will not be removed from the memory as long as there's a reference to the function.

Comment: @Teemu so jQuery doesn't hold any references to this handler, and it could get GC after a few seconds ?

Comment: I suppose jQuery keeps a reference, that's why it's recommended to remove all jQuery related elements with jQuery methods.

Comment: @Teemu so, if it holds a reference, that means it will never get GC, it's not using anything like `MutationObserver` to remove these references

Comment: @buga  Well jQuery does hold a reference to the control, so it will also hold onto this until that goes out of scope too. eg.  `var x = $('.control')`,   If `x` had say been used inside a `setInterval` that you never clear, this will stay in memory.  Basically as long as any references to the event, element no longer exist, then it should free the memory.

Comment: Old versions didn't use Mutation Observer, I'm not sure if newer are. I doubt that, though, as Mutation Observers are slowing page down.

Comment: And unless there is some bug with `jquery` it shouldn't even be needed.

Comment: SImilar question: [If a DOM Element is removed, are its listeners also removed from memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528049/if-a-dom-element-is-removed-are-its-listeners-also-removed-from-memory)